# Pydantic model with field names that have non-alphanumeric characters

Tags: python, json, fastapi, pydantic

I'm using FastAPI and want to build a pydantic model for the following request data json:

```json
  {
    "gas(euro/MWh)": 13.4,
    "kerosine(euro/MWh)": 50.8,
    "co2(euro/ton)": 20,
    "wind(%)": 60
  }
```

I defined the model like this:

```py
class Fuels(BaseModel):
    gas(euro/MWh): float
    kerosine(euro/MWh): float
    co2(euro/ton): int
    wind(%): int
```

Which naturally gives a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` for `wind(%)`.

So how can I define a pydantic model for a json that has non-alphanumeric characters in its keys?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use an **alias**, Pydantic's `Field` gives you the ability to use an alias.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class Fuels(BaseModel):
    gas: float = Field(..., alias="gas(euro/MWh)")
    kerosine: float = Field(..., alias="kerosine(euro/MWh)") 
    co2: int = Field(..., alias="co2(euro/ton)")
    wind: int = Field(..., alias="wind(%)")
```

Comment: How can I get class' field name from alias name?  Is it possible? gas(euro/MWh) -> gas

Comment: I am also in a need of something similar. But when i try to use this way, i am getting the issue:  ValueError: [TypeError("'FieldInfo' object is not iterable"), TypeError('vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute')]